# A martial art manga series about a samurai with animal's blood

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga a long time ago (3 or 4 years I think), it's drawing style seemed to look like *Vagabond*.

There was explicit mature content in that series but the story & drawing style was thrilling & interesting.

The story was about a fearsome samurai who has the blood, strength & intuition of an animal (maybe a wolf). That might because his father or mother was a half-animal person or has some kind of disease that made dots appear on his/her skin (and he/she would die soon after being infected).

In the first chapters the main character raped a princess - daughter of an ancient Japanese lord. In the next chapter he raped some other girls but to free them from illness or something else, I don't remember.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure it was "Bestia".

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/manga/6055/Bestia):

> Long, long ago, a woman who had coupled with a strange beast gave birth to a Saishi, a half-human half-beast creature, whose body was filled with venom. These brutal creatures were used in battle during times of unrest, but during times of peace, they were shunned and hated. Indeed, they were cursed.
>
> A Ronin samurai called Gen Tsukinosuke is one of the few surviving Saishis and the owner of a magnificent sword, the "Fangs of God." He travels in search of his estranged sister and sleeps with women who yearn for death, killing them with his deadly poison. The story takes place in the war-torn days at the end of the Edo period. With a destiny to be a Kaishi, Tsukinosuke is also being swallowed up by the harsh flow of history.